# What gets Destroyed?

Tags: smash-up

Given

- **Hang in There** - Play on one of your minions. Ongoing: If this minion would be destroyed, move it to another base and destroy this action instead.
- **Nukebot** - power 5 - Ongoing: After this minion is destroyed, destroy each other player's minions on this base.
- **Sacrifice** - Choose one of your minions. Draw cards equal to its power. Destroy that minion.

I am have a bit trouble figuring out when destroy triggers.

I play Sacrifice on a Nukebot that has Hang in There, what happens?  Which cards get destroyed and why?

Answer (score 6):

Stepping through it in order.

Start - **Nukebot** with **Hang in There** are on a base

Play **Sacrifice**

1. Choose one of your Minions - Choose **Nukebot**
2. Draw Cards equal to its power - draw 5 cards
3. Destroy that minion - prepare to destroy Nukebot, check Ongoing triggers
4. **Hang in There** triggers on *If this minion would be destroyed*
5. Move the Nukebot to another base
6. Destroy **Hang in There**

The trigger on **Nukebot** never fires because it is never destroyed.  The Hang in There prevents it.